# Java Runnable Jar IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

So I'm somewhat new to java and i'm creating a simple game with a friend of mine. I've reached a point where I want to release a jar file of it so people can play it. I exported a jar of the project in Eclipse with no problems. But when I run it, it just creates the JFrame and not the game. I CAN run it in eclipse with no issues but outside it doesn't work. I created a .bat file to launch the jar and found an error on the console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read<ImageIO.java:1388>
at images.ImageLoader.load<ImageLoader.java:10>
at main.base.init<base.java:37>
at main.base.run<base.java:73>
at java.lang.Thread.run<Thread.java:745>
```

I did check the manifest and it had the right main class set. So I'm out of ideas here...
Here's the code to my main file:

```
package main;

import images.ImageLoader;
import images.ImageManager;
import images.SpriteSheet;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class base extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    //CREDIT: Thanks to CodeNMore for some base code for the game
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 484, HEIGHT = 365, SCALE = 2, TILESIZE = 24; //484, 365, scale=2
    public static boolean running = false;
    public Thread gameThread;
    private BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    private static BufferedImage cl;
    public static BufferedImage console;
    private static ImageManager im;
    private static Player player;
    private static Level level;
    private String Level[] = {"/level1.png","/level2.png","/level3.png"};
    public static String currentLevel;

    private static HUDLoader hud;

    public void init(){
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();

        spriteSheet = loader.load("/spritesheet.png");
        SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
        im = new ImageManager(ss);
        player = new Player(im);

        console = loader.load("/console.png");
        hud = new HUDLoader(console);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());

        setLevel(Level[2]);
        cl = loader.load(currentLevel);
        level = new Level(cl);
    }

    public static BufferedImage getLevel(){
        return cl;
    }

    public void setLevel(String set){
        currentLevel = set;
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)return;

        running = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(!running)return;

        running = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void run(){
        init();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;

        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            render();
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void tick(){
        player.tick();
        hud.tick();
    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs ==  null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //RENDER

        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);

        level.render(g);
        player.render(g);
        hud.render(g);

        //Reset Render
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        base game = new base();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Legend of Taco");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

    public static Player getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }

    public static HUDLoader getHud(){
        return hud;
    }

    public static ImageManager getImageManager(){
        return im;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
~Tom

Comment: if you had to say, which of your arguments passed to methods is most likely wrong? which calls a file not found in your jar? did you load the extra files correctly or set them with a property?

Comment: you have several files that may be a problem the png's. The paths exist outside of eclipse, right? They are reachable without the full qualified path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using different Java version in eclipse. You could add JDK or JRE which you are using in outside.

select the Window menu->Preferences. Then select Java->Installed JRE’s. Then click Add.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be the problem. But it was my game being made in JavaSE 1.7 so I changed it to jre8 and it works!